# Is there a way to set first row as column heading in tabulator using ajax?

Tags: tabulator

I am using tabulator [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) to load a table using ajax.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://www.getmydata.com/now", //ajax URL 
    autoColumns: true,
});
```

It loads perfectly but doesn't load the first row as column headings. I need autoColumns to be set to true, because the ajax response is dynamic and the columns change. However the first row is always column headings. Tabulator is not picking up first row as heading.

I could not find relevant config to set first row as header.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `autocolumns` option, tabulator will pickup the column names from the data property names on the first row, not from an array of strings on the first row.

For example, with the data below:

```js
 var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
 ];
```

you would end up with 4 columns titled "name", "age", "col" and "dob".

Data must always be provided to Tabulator in this array of objects format regardless of how you are planning on using it.

If your server cannot provide data in this format, then you can use the `ajaxResponse` callback to take the incoming data from your server, reformat it, then return it from the function in the format Tabulator is expecting:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response.tableData; //return the tableData property of a response json object
    },
});
```

Full details on this can be found in the [Ajax Documentation[(http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data#ajax)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it would be a quick config option like `firstRowColumn:True`, but `ajaxResponse`  seems to work too. Appreciate your help.